# MVC: Editing model, extra-fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Dont beat me if it's been asked for many times.
I've seen a lot of nice presentations of how to edit entities using MVC. All they hope my edit form would contain only 3 fields which are of course editable and thus able to rotate data between client and server until user will finally enter correct values. But my app is a bit more complex and i need your advice.
1) I have an entity Product having fields Name and CreatedBy
2) The only editable field is Name
3) In case of incorrect input i need to re-populate non-editable fields with the best way

In purpose of this i need to retrieve business object from repo and assign missing values to the resulting viewmodel. There can be many values. Should i assign them step-by-step? Should i use (Try)UpdateModel? Should i use something like AutoMapper (never tried) to specify how to update entities by each other? What common ways are used for this? Please any liknks on edit forms that contain more than 3 editable fields... Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand when you say, " In case of incorrect input i need to re-populate non-editable fields with the best way."  Does this mean your non-editable fields are stored as hidden fields in the view?  Send me your view and what you hope to achieve on form submission or otherwise.

Comment: They aren't stored in hiddens, but if model is not valid then i need to return a view containing both editable and non-editable values to the user. As in controller i get only editable ones, i need to set others by my hands.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, "They aren't stored in hiddens, but if model is not valid then i need to return a view containing both editable and non-editable values to the user. As in controller i get only editable ones, i need to set others by my hands."  Here's how to do that:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function Create(company As Company) As ActionResult

    If ModelState.IsValid Then

        db.Companies.Add(company)
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")

    End If

    ' if model state is not valid
        Return RedirectToAction("MyNewAction")

End Function
```

If your modelstate is invalid, then send to another action (or view, if you so choose).  If you need to create a separate model, you can do that and then send the model to the new view with your added fields.

Comment: This action will not return input values to be corrected to user.

Comment: You could send the model (which will contain the input) to the action like this `Return RedirectToAction("Index", New With {.id=company.CompanyId})`

Comment: ModelState here will reset after a call. Also, there will be Http 302 Redirect which is not desireable. Also, suppose you have edit form with 10 editable fields and 10 which are non. Will you assign them all? They will drop into URL string :)

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, so this probably isn't the best way to approach it.  You have 10 editable fields, and why do you have 10 non-editable fields?  If they are non-editable, why do you want to edit them if the form is not valid?

Comment: It's common case when only a few fields are editable from all entity's information displayed on page. For example, in user profile page you can edit your name but yu're not able to change your login and account creation date.

Comment: Correct, but it appears that you want to let the user edit them if the form is not valid?  Why?

Comment: Nope. You give user an edit view with A, B, C and D fields where firsth two are editable. User sets values and posts the form back. The action gets only A and B and you need set C and D and send erroneous view back to user displaying what values were incorrect. My question is what's the best way to fill C and D.

Comment: ps: sorry if my english doesnt give a chance :)

Comment: Oh, that's so simple.  You're using a model, correct?  Then, you can access the models properties despite them not being sent via the view like `mymodel.myProperty`.  You update it the same as you would like `mymodel.SaveChanges()`.  You're using EF, right?  P.S.  Your english is good!

Comment: I'm using LINQ but i have also a business logic layer. So you think in case of !ModelState.Isvalid i should just Model.C = Foo; Model.D = Bar; before sending the view back?

Comment: You shouldn't have to send the variables back at all.  LINQ2Entities doesn't require that you set all the variables in an update query.